# Showing that $\mathrm{in}_<(f^m) = \mathrm{in}_<(f)^m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I am currently in the following scenario:

> Let $f\in K[x_1, ..., x_n]$, and $<$ be a fixed term order.  I want to show that $\mathrm{in}_<(f^m) = \mathrm{in}_<(f)^m$ (for some $m>0$).

First of all - is this actually true?  Intuitively, it makes and seems obvious to me.  I also can't figure out a counter example that would disprove this.  But I can't figure out how to formally prove it.  I've tried to go about it from definition, but it just seems too abstract to tackle it that way.

Any nudges / hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your notation $in_<(f)$ means the initial monomial of the polynomial $f$ (or, equivalently, the generator of the initial idea of the ideal $(f)$).

The statement is true.  Recall the inequalities about monomials that if $x^a<x^b$, then $x^{a+c}<x^{b+c}$ for any monomial $x^c$ (here, I'm using multi-index notation, so $x^a$ is really $x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2}\cdots x_n^{a_n}$).

Now, let $$f=ax^{\alpha}+\sum b_ix^{\beta_i}.$$  Here, I've chosen to separate out the leading term $ax^{\alpha}$ ($a\not=0$ and $x^{\alpha}>x^{\beta_i}$ for all $i$).

Now, consider $f^2$, we can write this as

$$f^2=a^2x^{2\alpha}+2ax^{\alpha}\sum b_ix^{\beta_i}+\left(\sum b_ix^{\beta_i}\right)^2.$$

Expanding this, we see that the monomials are all of the one of the following forms:
$$x^{2\alpha},x^{\alpha+\beta_i},x^{\beta_i+\beta_j}.$$

Since $x^{\alpha}>x^{\beta_i}$, we know that $x^{2\alpha}>x^{\alpha+\beta_i}$.  Also, since $x^{\alpha}>x^{\beta_j}$, $x^{\alpha+\beta_i}>x^{\beta_i+\beta_j}$.  Therefore, $x^{2\alpha}$ is *unique*, i.e., it shows up in a term of $f^2$ in the square exactly once.  Therefore, there is no cancellation and the leading term of $f^2$ is $a^2x^{2\alpha}$.

You can continue with induction to get that the leading term of $f^m$ is $a^mx^{m\alpha}$, which implies your claim.

Comment: @MichaelBurr - There was no typo in my question; I did indeed want to know about $in_<(f^m) = in_<(f)^m$.  Thanks for your answer! :)